# Problema al ordenar consultas metidas por el usuario

Tags: javascript, html, ordenamiento, quicksort

Estoy creando un programa que captura datos en una página usando JavaScript. Inserté el método de ordenamiento QuickSort para las consultas generales, sin embargo en la pantalla solo se muestra una consulta aun si metí más de una.

Éste es mi código:

```js
var menu;
var opccon;
var opccan;
var activo = [];
var activo = new Array();
var nombre = [];
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var i = 0;
var xnum;
var Tr = 1;
var num = [];
var num = new Array();
var renglon = 0;
var encontro = 0;
var min = 0;

do {
  menu = prompt("MENU PRINCIPAL \n 1.-Captura \n2.-Consulta \n3.-Actualizaciones \n4.-Cancelaciones \n5.-Salida");
  if (menu == 1) {
    activo = 0;
    xnum = prompt("Ingrese su Numero contable");
    for (x = 1; x <= renglon; x++) {
      if (xnum == num[x]) {
        encontro = 1;
      }
    }
    if (encontro == 0) {
      renglon = 0;
      for (x = 1; x <= renglon; x++) {
        if (num[x] != null) {
          renglon = renglon + 1;
        }
      }
      renglon = renglon + 1;
      num[renglon] = xnum;
      nombre[renglon] = prompt("Ingrese su NOMBRE");
      activo[renglon] = 1;
    }
    if (encontro == 1) {
      alert("Registro ya existente intente con otro registro");
    }
  }
  
  if (menu == 2) {
    do {
      opccon = prompt("MENU PRINCIPAL \n 1.-Registro \n2.-General \n3.-Regresar");
      if (opccon == 1) {
        encontro;
        xnum = prompt("Ingresa el numero de cuenta que desea encontrar")
        for (x = 1; x <= renglon; x++) {
          if (xnum == num[x]) {
            encontro = 1;
            alert("Nombre " + nombre[x] + " Numero de cuenta " + num[x]);
          }
        }
        if (encontro == 0) {
          alert("Disculpe el numero que ingreso no esta en la base de datos ");
        }
      }

      if (opccon == 2) {
        function stableSort(v, f) {
          if (f === undefined) {
            f = function(a, b) {
              a = "" + a;
              b = "" + b;
              return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
            }
          }
          var dv = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            dv[i] = [v[i], i];
          }
          dv.sort(function(a, b) {
            return f(a[0], b[0]) || (a[1] - b[1]);
          });
          for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            v[i] = dv[i][0];
          }
        }
        num.sort();
        for (x = 1; x <= renglon; x++) {
          alert("Clave: " + num + "\n" + "Nombre: " + nombre);
        }
      }
    } while (opccon != 3);
  }
  
  if (menu == 3) {
    encontro = 1;
    xnum = prompt("Ingresa el numero de cuenta que desea encontrar");
    for (x = 1; x <= renglon; x++) {
      if (xnum == num[x]) {
        encontro = 1;
        alert("Nombre: " + nombre[x] + " Numero de cuenta: " + num[x]);
        nombre[x] = prompt("Digite de nuevo el Nombre");
        alert("Nombre cambiado");
      }
    }

    if (encontro == 0)
    {
      alert("Disculpe el numero que ingreso no esta en la base de datos");
    }
  }
  if (menu == 4) {
    do {
      opccan = prompt("MENU \n 1.-Fisicas \n2.-Logicas \n3.-Reinstalaciones \n4.-Regresar");
      if (opccan == 1) {
        encontro = 0;
        xnum = prompt("Ingrese número");
        for (x = 1; x <= renglon; x++) {
          if (xnum == num[x]) {
            encontro = 1;
            alert("Nombre " + nombre[x] + " Numero de cuenta " + num[x] + "será eliminado");
            num[x] = 0;
            nombre[x] = null;
            xnum[x] = null;
            activo[x] = 0;
          }
        }
        if (encontro == 0) {
          alert("No se encontro el registro ingresado ");
        }
      }

      if (opccan == 2) {
        xnum = prompt("Ingrese número");
        for (x = 1; x <= renglon; x++) {
          if (xnum == num[x]) {
            alert("Nombre " + nombre[x] + " Numero de cuenta " + num[x] + " será eliminado");
            activo[x] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      
      if (opccan == 3) {
        xnum = prompt("Ingrese número");
        for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
          if (xnum == num[x]) {
            if (activo[x] == 0) {
              activo[x] = 1;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } while (opccan != 4);
  }
} while (menu != 5);
```

```html
<title>Documento sin t&iacute;tulo</title>
```

Comment: En que opción se metes las consultas que luego ordenas.

Comment: Por que todo con `alert()` muchos navegadores dan la opción de bloquear este tipo de notificaciones por lo molestas que son

Comment: porque, por que motivo en el mundo ibas a hacer esto? `var activo = [];
var activo = new Array();` pobres programadores de JS, a veces vemos cada mierda... y luego haces `activo = 0;` enfin... entre eso, y los `if` con `do whiles` en medio, creo que te falta un poco de base de programacion, mas que que tu programa no funcione

Comment: Cambia tus **alert** por **console.log** para depurar de forma más cómoda la ejecución del codigo !!  Además hay un error en la comprobación de la entrada, solo te pemite UNA y para el resto te indica que ya existe

Answer (score 0):

Tienes multitud de problemas en tu código.

En lo que comentas de la función de ordenación, sí la incluyes en el código pero no la llamas en ningún momento. En ningún punto del código se llama a la función `stableSort`.

Por otro lado si mantienes los datos en 3 arrays diferentes (`num`, `nombre` y `activo`), y quieres ordenar la información, el problema es que tendrías que mantener los 3 arrays sincronizados. Si ordenas únicamente uno de ellos ya no vas a poder encontrar la correspondencia de los datos. Es mejor utilizar un único array y en cada posición del array almacenar toda la información de un registro.

También hay otros cambios que podrías hacer en tu código como:

Utilizar `switch` en lugar de múltiples `if` (creo que aportaría claridad al código).

Utilizar variables locales dentro de cada bloque de código definidas con `let` (también por una cuestión de limpieza y claridad).

Extraer a funciones código repetido como la petición de una clave o un nombre al usuario.

Aunque he mantenido el interfaz utilizando `prompt` y `alert` en mi ejemplo no es recomendable (como ya te han apuntado en los comentarios) mantener este interfaz como definitivo. Por múltiples razones: los navegadores tienden a bloquearlos, es poco amistoso (yo diría que incluso molesto) para el usuario, no da flexibilidad ni posibilidad de personalización, etc.

Aquí te dejo una modificación de tu código aplicando estas ideas:

```js
function stableSort(v, f) {
    if (f === undefined) {
        f = function (a, b) {
            a = "" + a;
            b = "" + b;
            return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }
    let dv = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        dv[i] = [v[i], i];
    }
    dv.sort(function (a, b) {
        return f(a[0], b[0]) || (a[1] - b[1]);
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        v[i] = dv[i][0];
    }
}

function preguntarClave() {
    const xnum = prompt('Ingrese su Número contable');
    const num = parseInt(xnum);
    if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0) {
        // Número no válido
        alert('Número no válido');
        return null;
    }
    return num;
}

function preguntarNombre(msg) {
    let nombre = prompt((msg ? msg + '\n' : '') + 'Ingrese su NOMBRE');
    if (nombre && (nombre = nombre.trim())) {
        return nombre;
    }
    // Nombre vacío o sólo espacios
    alert('No ha introducido un nombre correcto');
    return null;
}

var nombres = [];
var menu;

do {
    menu = prompt(
        "MENU PRINCIPAL\n1.-Captura\n2.-Consulta\n3.-Actualizaciones\n4.-Cancelaciones\n5.-Salida");
    switch (menu) {
    case '1':
        {
            let num = preguntarClave();
            if (num != null) {

                if (nombres.findIndex(x => x.Num === num) >= 0) {
                    // El registro ya existe
                    alert('Registro ya existente intente con otro registro');
                    break;
                }
                let nombre = preguntarNombre();
                if (nombre) {
                    nombres.push({ Num: num, Nombre: nombre, Activo: true });
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case '2':
        {
            let opccon;
            do {
                opccon = prompt('MENU PRINCIPAL\n1.-Registro\n2.-General\n3.-Regresar');
                switch (opccon) {
                case '1':
                    {
                        let num = preguntarClave();
                        let encontro = nombres.find(x => x.Num === num && x.Activo);
                        if (encontro) {
                            alert(`Nombre: ${encontro.Nombre}\nNúmero de cuenta: ${encontro.Num}`);
                        } else {
                            alert('Disculpe el número que ingresó no está en la base de datos');
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case '2':
                    {
                        stableSort(nombres, (a, b) => a.Nombre < b.Nombre ? -1 : (a.Nombre > b.Nombre ? 1 : 0));
                        let lista = nombres.filter(x => x.Activo).reduce(
                            (prev, current) => prev + 'Clave: ' + current.Num + ' Nombre: ' + current.Nombre + '\n',
                            '');
                        alert(lista);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } while (opccon !== '3');
        }
        break;
    case '3':
        {
            let num = preguntarClave();
            let encontro = nombres.find(x => x.Num === num && x.Activo);
            if (!encontro) {
                alert('Disculpe el número que ingresó no está en la base de datos');
                break;
            }

            let nombre = preguntarNombre(`Nombre: ${encontro.Nombre} Número de cuenta: ${encontro.Num}`);
            if (nombre) {
                encontro.Nombre = nombre;
                alert('Nombre cambiado');
            }
        }
        break;
    case '4':
        {
            let opccan;
            do {
                opccan = prompt('MENU\n1.-Físicas\n2.-Lógicas\n3.-Reinstalaciones\n4.-Regresar');
                switch (opccan) {
                case '1':
                    {
                        let num = preguntarClave();
                        let index = nombres.findIndex(x => x.Num === num);
                        if (index < 0) {
                            alert('No se encontró el registro ingresado');
                            break;
                        }
                        alert(`Nombre :${nombres[index].Nombre}\nNúmero de cuenta: ${nombres[index].Num}\nEl registro será eliminado`);
                        nombres.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case '2':
                    {
                        let num = preguntarClave();
                        let encontro = nombres.find(x => x.Num === num && x.Activo);
                        if (!encontro) {
                            alert(`El registro ${num} no existe`);
                            break;
                        }
                        alert(`Nombre :${encontro.Nombre}\nNúmero de cuenta: ${encontro.Num}\nEl registro será eliminado`);
                        encontro.Activo = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case '3':
                {
                    let num = preguntarClave();
                    let encontro = nombres.find(x => x.Num === num);
                    if (!encontro) {
                        alert(`El registro ${num} no existe`);
                        break;
                    }
                    encontro.Activo = true;
                    alert(`Nombre :${encontro.Nombre}\nNúmero de cuenta: ${encontro.Num}\nEl registro se ha restituido`);

                }
                }
            } while (opccan !== '4')
        }
        break;
    }
} while (menu !== '5');
```